# Delete fork dependency of a GitHub repository

Tags: github

How can I make GitHub forget or disassociate that my repo was originally a fork of another project?

I forked a project in GitHub. I can now see "forked from whatever/whatever". The parent repository "whatever/whatever" is no longer maintained. I have been allowed to continue use of the code base of the original repository to create an independent repository.

Is there a way to detach my project from the original repository?

Comment: The specific answer to this question has only a few votes on it. Find the answer below by @antonio O. With this approach, there's no need to delete any repository and start from scratch: existing PRs and branches remain untouched.

Comment: @macetw Isn't Antonio O's answer only applicable to GitHub Enterprise though?

Answer (score 338, accepted):

**Update Jan 2022:**

Use the GitHub chatbot-virtual-assistant at https://support.github.com/contact?tags=rr-forks&subject=Detach%20Fork&flow=detach_fork

**First answer:**
You can [contact github support](https://github.com/contact) and ask them to switch your repository to "normal mode".

On [this page](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/#commit-was-made-in-a-fork), "Commit was made in a fork" paragraph, it is explained that one has to go through support to switch. Therefore, it is likely that there is no way to do that by yourself (unless you destroy and recreate your repo which is explained before... if you do so be careful if you have tickets or a wiki attached to your project as they ***will*** be deleted!).

Comment: I can confirm that contacting Support works flawlessly, plus they often reply in a matter of hours :-)

Comment: The linked page no longer contains the information stated.

Comment: @MattBrennan The page changed but the last section still includes: "To detach the fork and turn it into a standalone repository on GitHub.com or GitHub Enterprise, contact GitHub support or your site administrator, respectively."

Comment: I worked with our admin, we used the site admin->Database->Make Root so you can set the then forked repo as the Root of the network, this will detach the original repo from the network

Comment: But what happens, if I clone the repo, change its name, and upload it back on an eventually different account? This might be a security issue. Or is there a way to not allow it? Clone might be mirror or the like ...

Comment: The security that git provides to you is the fact that a commit includes the hashes of all of its content so you won't be able to change the content without recreating the commit. What it does not provide is a way to prove that repo A is really a mirror of B (without cloning both) as well preventing you from merging your work against a malicious branch.

Comment: Tickets as in issues? They are kept, at least now. Not sure how it was before.

Comment: In Github Enterprise you can find it now under admin->Collaboration->Network and depending on your use case you should use 'Make Root', 'Detach' or 'Extract'.

Comment: @BenC is that sarcasm?

Comment: @AnisLOUNIS: no, it wasn't, but it was over 6 years ago so things might be different now.

Comment: I wish GitHub wouldn't treat forks as second class citizens, making this kind of "detachment" even necessary. Forks should retain their inheritance from parent forks and they should be treated equally as "root" repos. There's no shame in working on a fork but rather pride in collaborating with and inheriting from others, and we shouldn't have to erase that inheritance in order for the repo to have first-class treatment.

Comment: It appears that _private_ forks cannot be un-forked without the upstream repository owner's consent, which I find utterly bizarre, given that I can straight-up delete my private fork. I encountered this limitation while using the chat-bot.

Comment: Well, it takes me 3 hours for github support team to detach the fork though.

Comment: I request detaching two forks via the virtual assistant 10 minutes ago, and both are detached after 5 minutes :O

Comment: For those who may have multiple accounts, or owns organizations, make sure you select the correct account that owns the repo to be detached!

Comment: Strangely, "the parent repository is abandoned" is not listed among the reasons you can choose on why to detach. So I picked "The repository has diverged significantly from its parent"...

Answer (score 122):

You could duplicate the forked repository to a new repository (without the fork dependency) from the GitHub UI, then remove the original forked one:

- Sign in to GitHub
- Select the **+** sign in the top right corner and select **Import repository**.
- Import your forked repository. The new repository won't have the fork dependency.
- Delete the original, forked repository in the repository settings.

**NOTE: This approach will not preserve issues and pull requests.**

Comment: Has anyone else had an issue with the import feature "hanging"? Mine has been on "Detecting your project’s version control system…" for about 5 hours. I'm not sure if I am being queued or it's an actual hang. The repo is small. Tempted to leave it over night just in case I'm in a line.

Comment: I finally got curious and just clicked "cancel". Clicking cancel allowed it to skip the VCS detection and just import the code/commits/branches etc. This was the case when importing Github --> Github. The import might not have hung if I was coming from a different VCS? Not sure. Please also note on doing this with a second repo, I had to cancel twice for it to work. If CLI copies all the same data that might be a better method, but hope this helps others that chose this route.

Comment: Just to be clear, this approach will not preserve issues and pull requests.

Comment: Easy solution without requiring a support email. All commits get registered too. Really nice

Comment: Not work. Maybe the target repo is private?

Answer (score 47):

Make sure you have all the important branches and tags on your local repo, delete the github repo, recreate the repository through usual means (no forking) and push the local repository back with `git push --all`. Note that if you have local branches that you don't want to publish, might be worth to create a temporary clean local clone for the operation.

However, this will also get rid of wiki and issues. As the wiki is in fact it's own repository, it can be handled similarly by cloning it and then recreating and pushing. The repo address is on wiki's Git Access page (`git@github.com:user/repo.wiki.git`).

This leaves issues. They can be exported through the [API](http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/), but as far as I know, you can only create issues and comments with your person, so importing them perfectly is impossible.

So, if you need issues to be preserved, you should go through github support as Thomas Moulard suggests.

Comment: Depending on how many issues there are, it might be possible to transfer them one by one to the new repository before deleting from the old one from the web (https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/transferring-an-issue-to-another-repository). I guess a determined individual could transfer more than 100 issues per hour - not a fun, but for many repositories a doable thing.

Answer (score 33):

Log in to GitHub with your credentials.

Go to https://support.github.com/contact?tags=rr-forks&subject=Detach%20Fork&flow=detach_fork

Choose "Detach", then enter the URL or repo name of the fork as `your-user-name/repository-name`, and answer the other questions of the virtual assistant.

You will get an email with a ticket number where you can check the status of your request. You will also be notified per email once your repo has been deforked.

Most repository settings will stay unchanged, including user permissions, stargazers, issues, PRs, discussions, etc.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly, and I was able to use the virtual assistant from Firefox (94.0.2).

Comment: Great answer, thanks. By the way, if you have not committed to the fork, assistant recommends to delete fork and clone the original repository instead. [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/g1qjKlV)

Answer (score 28):

I got the similar problem, and ended up using this [github help page](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/) to solve it. I didn't mind about the wiki and issues tracker as it was for my blog using a theme kindly developed by another user.

To detach a forked repo and use it as your own after several commits without losing the whole history:

`git clone --bare  git@github.com:user/forked_repo.git`

Create a new empty reposity `new-repository` on the github website.
And push a mirrored version:

`cd user.github.com.git/`

`git push --mirror git@github.com:user/new-repository.git`

One can rename on github, the `forked_repository` with another name to keep it as backup and check updates if needed. Or simply delete it.

Renaming the `new-repository` to the original name does the job. As a side effect, your commits now appear in your history.

Comment: Been waiting for response from the support for over 3 hours. However, this worked for me. Saved my 81 days commit streak :)) Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

Using the info from [aurelien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1395352/aurelien) and [Clayton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/30753/clayton), I was able to do this with the following:

```
$ git clone --bare https://github.com/my/forked_repo.git
<delete forked_repo on GitHub>
<recreate repo on GitHub using same name>
$ cd forked_repo.git
$ git push --mirror
```

Here's the [documentation for `git clone --bare`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone):

> Make a bare Git repository. That is, instead of creating `<directory>` and placing the administrative files in `<directory>/.git`, make the `<directory>` itself the `$GIT_DIR`. This obviously implies the -n because there is nowhere to check out the working tree. Also the branch heads at the remote are copied directly to corresponding local branch heads, without mapping them to `refs/remotes/origin/`. When this option is used, neither remote-tracking branches nor the related configuration variables are created.

Here's the [documentation for `git push --mirror`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push):

> Instead of naming each ref to push, specifies that all refs under `refs/` (which includes but is not limited to `refs/heads/`, `refs/remotes/`, and `refs/tags/`) be mirrored to the remote repository. Newly created local refs will be pushed to the remote end, locally updated refs will be force updated on the remote end, and deleted refs will be removed from the remote end. This is the default if the configuration option `remote.<remote>.mirror` is set.

Note: like the other `git` based answers, this will not copy over issues that are not part of the `git` repo such as the wiki and issues. Per Tapio:

- The wiki is a separate git repo and can be handled in a similar fashion per Tapio. The address is: `git@github.com:user/repo.wiki.git`.
- Issues can be exported via the GitHub API but there are issues recreating them since they can only be created by your user, so imports will lose information.

Comment: This did exactly what I wanted. Thanks!!

Answer (score 17):

**This only applies to GitHub Enterprise, not on github.com**

This approach will preserve all the branches, pull requests, and everything else, but it requires the user to be logged in to an account that has admin privileges.

1. Log in with admin privileges
2. Go to the repository that you need to detach: `https://<ghe url>/<org>/<repo>`
3. Click on the “Site Admin” rocket on the top right corner
4. Click "Collaboration" on the top menu bar
5. Click on “Network” on the left pane
6. Click on “Detach” in the Network Structure pane
7. Accept

This was tested on GitHub Enterprise 3.3

Comment: Depending on your use case, 'Detach' or 'Extract' might be more appropriate.
I find 'Make Root' a bit weird as it will basically invert the current root->child direction. (Github Enterprise 2.17)

Answer (score -1):

If you do not need any past commits (I didn't in my case), you can just:

- fork the project
- make a local copy of the fork (I used my IDE to do that)
- delete the git folder from your local copy
- commit the project as you normally would a new project.

You can just delete the fork from your github account after. Took me all of one minute and worked like a charm.