# How to transfer a repository on Github thats been forked with changes

Tags: github

I have made some new commits in a fork. There are no branches (only master). The original account owner wants to transfer control to the whole code base to us, his original code plus the changes I have made since in the fork. What's the best way to do this and preserve history etc. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOTHING.

Since git is a distributed vcs this is actually pretty easy. You already have the history included in your fork. If there are not changes in the original after your fork then you are done.

If there are changes in the original after your fork, merge them in using normal git workflow and keep your copy.

EDIT:

Good explanation of distributed vcs: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/why-you-should-switch-from-subversion-to-git

EDIT:

Github allows owners of private repositories to control their forks. So I see two options:

1) look at this: https://help.github.com/articles/how-to-transfer-a-repository. The caveat is that you can only transfer the root repo, so you have to get your changes into that.

2) `git clone` the repo onto your local computer. Then follow GitHub's instructions on how to create a new repository. You can clone your fork and not worry about extra merging.
https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo

Personally I like option 2 if you don't care about any of the GitHub artifacts such as pull requests...

Comment: I'm new to git although I'm familiar with source control. How do you merge them in using normal git workflow. Do you mean that commits I make to the fork automatically get reflected in the account owners original? Trying to understand what I need to do to essentially help my company take control of the code base. Right now the fork is forked off the previous developers repo.

Comment: On github you should see something that says your fork is out of date from the original.

Comment: And it will give you the option to merge online. Let me know if that works.

Comment: and to clarify, this is only if the original has been updated after you forked.

Comment: I don't think the original has been updated since the fork and I made my changes

Comment: Are there other branches on the original besides master? If not, you have the entire repo in your control right now, with all history and original code. You don't have to do anything else.

Comment: The issue is that the original owner changed some settings and I could not get access to my fork. He's put those settings back now, so I can see it again. But it caused us some concern that we were not working on a fork that we had control over.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38924/discussion-between-johnny-z-and-brad-thomas)

Comment: I have up-voted your answer. Thank you for the time you spent on this. I also found this link last night... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052477/how-can-i-delete-fork-dependency-of-my-repository-on-github