# Modify fork dependency of GitHub repository after forking?

Tags: github

For example: users `Foo` and `Bar` each fork a `Project` from a repository which user `Baz` created.

On the GitHub website, their projects both indicate "forked from Baz/Project".

How would (or "can") user Foo modify their fork dependency after the initial forking such that Foo is "forked from Bar/Project"?

Per answers to the question, "[Delete fork dependency of a GitHub repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16052477/5225057)" perhaps this is something to request from [GitHub user support](https://github.com/contact)? If, however, there is a means to modify this dependency either through the GitHub website or the CLI with `git` tools, that would be preferable.