# Is there Any method to unfork a github repository without deleting it

Tags: github

Is there Any method to unfork a github repository without deleting it

(except Gitbash using following method)

```
 git clone --bare https://github.com/{username}/{repository} 

https://github.com/{username}/{repository}/settings

https://github.com/new.

cd {repository}.git and git push --mirror 

https://github.com/{username}/{repository}
```

Comment: Check if unsetting upstream is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046436/how-do-you-stop-tracking-a-remote-branch-in-git

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete fork dependency of a GitHub repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052477/delete-fork-dependency-of-a-github-repository)