# De-forking a Github repo

Tags: github, fork, git-submodules

Is it possible to 'de-fork' a GitHub repo? The situation is as follows. I have forked a repo and then added some scripts to it. But then I realized it might be more sensible to use the original repo as a git submodule. So I want to refactor my now-fork in such a way that it is no longer a fork, but uses the original repo as a submodule.

I believe I could simply remove all files forked from the original repo (leaving only my own added scripts), add the original as a submodule and commit. But then I guess it would still be flagged as a fork on github.

What is the best practice here?

Comment: Don't think you can un-flag that. You'll have to create a new repository.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete fork dependency of a GitHub repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052477/delete-fork-dependency-of-a-github-repository)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do that would be to

- Click **Import repository** [image]
- Then linking to the repository you forked (your link and not the original repository).
- Add new repository details and click *Begin Import*
- Delete the forked repository once import finishes

I hope this helps.

**Edit**

In order to *preserve* everything, you will have to contact GitHub support, as mentioned on [this page](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/#commit-was-made-in-a-fork). Doing so will keep everything you want

> To detach the fork and turn it into a standalone repository on GitHub, contact [GitHub Support](https://github.com/contact). If the fork has forks of its own, let support know if the forks should move with your repository into a new network or remain in the current network.

Comment: No, I don't have problems with 'importing' or submodules. I also want to 'preserve commit continuity' of my repo so other users who have already cloned my now-fork don't have many problems. Your answer basically is 'Throw away your repo and create a new one'. That is not what I want.

Comment: I did contact then and it really seems it is the only way. Thank you.