# Assuming I already have a public fork of a public repo, how do I make my repo private, while preserving all issues and PRs etc?

Tags: git, github

THe assumption here is that nothing changes except the fact that the repo becomes private. And since the repo has diverged significantly from the original, I'm not particularly fussed about upstream changes/updates.

Comment: Just go to the settings for your repository and select "Make Private"?

Comment: GitHub prevents me from doing so: "Public forks can’t be made private. Please duplicate the repository". Unfortunately this seems to be creating a new repository with just commits preserved - no info regarding issues, PRs etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete fork dependency of a GitHub repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052477/delete-fork-dependency-of-a-github-repository)

Comment: @Zeitounator not really, as in that question the original repository was deleted which lead to different problems than here.

Answer (score 1):

A fork of a public repository is itself a public repository. This can not be changed on Github - for comprehensible reasons: Making the fork of a public repository private would 1) mean to counteract the author's intention of having public code (possibly even violate the author's license), 2) possibly break dependencies and dependents, 3) make it impossible for others to work on your fork. The last one is especially important as your fork will be shown and being linked to in the original repository for public collaboration.

A solution, if you really want to do this, is to create a new project from the existing one. If you really think of the code as independent from the original and do not have the intention of putting them back together, then it can be feasible to create a new (private) repository of your own and host the code there.

Alternatively, if you just want to develop in private, create your public fork, work on it and refrain from pushing your local changes to remote. This way you can develop your solution and stay private while you do it, and later you publish and PR.

Although, please note, both of these approaches are not quite compatible to the collaborative idea of Git and should only be used if a) you what that you really need one of those, b) are sure you are allowed to privatise that code, c) are working alone.