# Can I set default repository for pull requests from fork?

Tags: github, pull-request

I have a fork of an old, not-very-well-supported repository. In the fork, whenever I create a pull request from feature branch to `master` (i.e. the default branch), I have to specify base repository manually, every single time:

[image: specify PR base repository manually]

<sup>*There's [a similar issue with BitBucket](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/When-creating-a-Pull-Request-in-a-Fork-repository-the-default/qaq-p/145584); it has a well description, but the answers are out of scope for this one.*</sup>

**Can I change this behavior of GitHub UI somehow, so that new pull requests are created against specific repository?**

---

I assume that I can achieve this by [de-forking the repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052477/delete-fork-dependency-of-a-github-repository), but I'd like to keep the fork relation *a)* due to historical reasons, *b)* out of respect to the original author, and *c)* because this is a highly error-prone process for now (there's no single button for that, unfortunately)

Comment: same question TAT

Answer (score 1):

While [changing the base branch of an existing PR](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/changing-the-base-branch-of-a-pull-request) is supported, changing the actual upstream repository is not for now (Q1 2022)

I would:

- make a new fork of the target upstream repository
- change origin of my local repository to that new fork and push my PR branches to it
- make new PR from that new fork: this tie, the base repository is the right one every time.
- possibly push the same feature branch to my old fork, which remains tied to the old upstream repository

Comment: Im not sure this addresses the concern that when a new PR is opened its defaulted to the upstream as the base instead of the forked repo. Its not so much that we want the upstream to be changed, just the default behavior for new PR's on which base its comparing to.

Comment: @Chase But the base repository will be the right one with this new setup, right?

Comment: While it somewhat works, I guess the real answer is still just, No, you cant change the default base repo for new pull requests that you open. You will always need to change the base before submitting it.

Comment: @Chase Indeed. I hope GitHub would consider this use case. Maybe it is tricky to implement though.