# Got stuck while uploading in public repository in Github via Git

Tags: git, github, repository, fork, public

In the init add and commit stages it goes smoothly but during push stage, it shows error.
[Image containing error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojv77.png)

```
Uploading LFS objects:   0% (0/100), 0 B | 0 B/s, done.
batch response: @KIVUOS1999 can not upload new objects to public fork KIVUOS1999/shooting
batch response: @KIVUOS1999 can not upload new objects to public fork KIVUOS1999/shooting
batch response: @KIVUOS1999 can not upload new objects to public fork KIVUOS1999/shooting
batch response: @KIVUOS1999 can not upload new objects to public fork KIVUOS1999/shooting
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/KIVUOS1999/shooting'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052477/delete-fork-dependency-of-a-github-repository

Answer (score 6):

You can't use Git LFS on a fork.

> Git LFS on github.com does not currently support pushing LFS objects to public forks. GitHub Enterprise does support this behavior.

https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/1906#issuecomment-276602035

Comment: so is there a way that I can upload this project in Github or Github like websites so that I and my friend can work together?

Comment: I and my friend is doing a project in unity, can you please suggest me anyway so that we can work together.

Comment: Try : git clone to DIR1 ; mkdir DIR2 ; cp from DIR1 to DIR2 ; then create repo from DIR2 ; apply https://git-lfs.com/

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "my commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin https://github.com/barkhayot/testingfor-.git
git push -u origin main
```

Comment: try like that .. and hope that will help

Comment: but that will upload my files to your repository I don't want that. I already have a repository which I have forked from my friend I want to push to that repository