# fail to upload a large file (>100MB) to a Github fork

Tags: git, git-lfs, git-fork

I am in a hackathon and need to submit by uploading my code to a fork. But when I try to upload big files to a fork of a GitHub repo I run into problems.

Since I am uploading a file that is larger than 100MB, I find that I need to use LFS for this, because if I don't use it, I will get the error below.
I am trying to upload a file(>100MB) to a GitHub fork, and below are m attempts.
Firstly, I try to upload it in the normal way using codes like these

```
git add -A
git commit -m "commit"
git push
```

but I get a error message like below, saying that I need to use a lfs for uploading.

```
Total 52 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (8/8), completed with 5 local objects.
remote: error: Trace: 94c833f2eae8c2fcc4591328fcef856bed345956a24bfd93ebb229e6887f01c2
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File assets/blocksLibrary.tres is 177.55 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
```

after running codes like this and push again

```
git install lfs
git lfs track "assets/blocksLibrary.tres"
```

then I get a error like this, saying lfs does not support pushing big file to a fork

```
Uploading LFS objects:   0% (0/27), 0 B | 0 B/s, done.
batch response: @hanzili can not upload new objects to public fork hanzili/Humans-vs-Quantum-Computers---IBM
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/hanzili/Humans-vs-Quantum-Computers---IBM.git'
```

I also try with increasing the buffer and switching to HTTP/1 but neither of them works for me

I did research I find know that it is impossible to push large files using LFS to a fork([Got stuck while uploading in public repository in Github via Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64400301/got-stuck-while-uploading-in-public-repository-in-github-via-git)). I understand LFS won't work for my situation (I do not have write access to the parent repo), so I am wondering is there any other way to achieve this?
Can anyone help with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Or how about (gasp) consulting the docs? https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/collaboration-with-git-large-file-storage#pushing-large-files-to-forks

Comment: yes, thanks for replying. I have read through all these documents before writing this. I guess I do not make myslef clear.

Comment: It's perfectly clear. You can't use LFS with a fork.

Comment: yes, I just wan to ask if there is an alternative way to achieve this, because I think is should be common to upload of file greater than 100MB to a fork

Comment: It doesn't matter what you think should be. What matters is what is: "You can push Git LFS objects to public forks if the repository network already has Git LFS objects or you have write access to the root of the repository network." The end.